# Plausible ways to discover higher order fourier analysis

Tags: nt.number-theory, additive-combinatorics, arithmetic-progression

[Szemeredi's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di%27s_theorem) is a difficult theorem that falls into the category of not obviously  foundational or widely applicable in itself but where the search for proofs have led to a number of significant new discoveries and developments.

One such is the theory of Higher Order Fourier Analysis originally developed in Tim Gowers' groundbreaking papers on a new proof of Szemeredi's Theorem with quantitative bounds.

**My question is whether there are other non-historical but nonetheless plausible ways to discover or invent this theory?**

Comment: If one is interested in detailed structure of topological dynamical systems, one could plausibly decide that nilsystems (i.e. translations on compact quotients of nilpotent Lie groups) form an interesting class, and that nilsequences are of special interest.  One may develop the theory of 2-step nilsequences, as Host and Kra [did here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.3241).  I'm leaving this as a comment because I can't really imagine sustaining the effort only to understand a class of dynamical systems.